# VBA code to select a value from webform dropdown based on value in excel workbook

Tags: html, vba, excel, dropdown

I'm needing to select a value from a webform dropdown based on the value in the excel book where I'm writing the macro.  So far I've been able to navigate to the website and click the desired tab with the following vba code:

```vb
Sub FillInternetForm()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Navigate "website I'm navigating to"
    ie.Visible = True
    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents 'wait until IE is done loading page.
    Wend

    Set AllHyperLinks = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
    For Each Hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
        If Hyper_link.innerText = "Reconciliations" Then
            Hyper_link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Next, I'm needing to click either "Preparer", "Approver", or "Reviewer" based on a predefined value (cell reference) within the workbook where I'm attempting to write the macro.  Below is the html coding that I believe I need to reference within my macro to perform the action described:

```
<td class="DashControlTableCellRight"><select name="ctl00$MainContent$ucDashboardPreparer$ucDashboardSettings$ctl00$ddlRoles" class="ControlDropDown" id="ctl00_MainContent_ucDashboardPreparer_ucDashboardSettings_ctl00_ddlRoles" onchange="OnRoleChanged(this);">
<option selected="selected" value="Preparer">Preparer</option>
<option value="Reviewer">Reviewer</option>
<option value="Approver">Approver</option>

</select></td>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I first want to point out that using `ie.busy` by itself is dangerous. `.busy` is very unreliable when you are automating web pages, and I would recommend that you also include the `.readyState` property in your loop.

> See this test I ran using a loop using `.readyState < 4`:
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Notice how `.Busy` was true for the first 5 lines, then became false on line 6? This is where your code would have thought the webpage was loaded. However, `.readyState` was still 1 *(which is the equivalent to `READYSTATE_LOADING`)*
>
> All of a sudden it became busy again until `.readystate = 4` (`READYSTATE_COMPLETE`).

I have moved your `.busy` method into a separate sub because this is something that is called quite often when navigating web pages.

```
Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.busy Or ie.readystate < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub

Sub FillInternetForm()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.navigate "website I'm navigating to"
    ie.Visible = True

    iebusy ie

    Set AllHyperLinks = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
    For Each Hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
        If Hyper_link.innerText = "Reconciliations" Then
            Hyper_link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    iebusy ie

    Dim mySelection As String, mySelObj As Object
    Set mySelObj = ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ucDashboardPreparer_ucDashboardSettings_ctl00_ddlRoles")

    'set your selection here
    mySelection = "Preparer"    'or Reviewer    or Approver
    Select Case mySelection
    Case "Preparer", "Reviewer", "Approver"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Selection!"
        ie.Quit
        Exit Sub
    End Select

    mySelObj.Value = mySelection

End Sub
```

The `mySelObj` is the object that will set your selection.

Comment: K.Davis - Thanks you very much for the detail you provided in response to my question.  When I debug I'm getting the following error on the following code line

Comment: Error: The remote server machine does not exist or is invalid

Comment: Code Line: Set mySelObj = ie.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$MainContent$ucDashboardPreparer$ucDashboardSettings$ctl00$ddlRoles")(0)

Comment: @GrantBangerter Can you recheck if that name in your HTML you provided changed? If so we will need to look at a different route. Also, usually that error means that you closed out of ie - you may want to set `ie.visible = False` so you don't accidentally close it.

Comment: @K.Davis - Your suggestion resolved my error issue, however, I'm also getting an error on your 2nd to last code line: "my SelfObj.Value = mySelection" that error being "Object Variable or With block variable not set." I may be missing a step here.  Thank you for your patience as I'm a newbie here.

Comment: @GrantBangerter Right above that line, type `MsgBox mySelObj Is Nothing` and tell me if it's true or false.

Comment: @K.Davis - Following your latest instruction, the message box returned "True"

Comment: @GrantBangerter This may be the case where your ID updates on every new page load. I have slightly updated my code. Try that and let me know.

Comment: @K.Davis - Your latest updated resolved my issue.  Thanks you very much for your help and timely responses.