# Using IE.Document.getElementById to auto fill webforms

Tags: excel, vba, webforms, getelementbyid

I'm having troubles getting VBA to autofill a webform from an excel spreadsheet. Here is my html code.

```htm
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
<br>
  <div>
  1&emsp;
  <label for="part1">&emsp;</label>
  <input type="text" id="part1_id" name="part1_name">
  <label for="action1">&emsp;</label>
  <input type="text" id="action1_id" name="action1_name">
  <label for="quanity1">&emsp;</label>
  <input type="text" id="quanity1_id" name="quanity1_name">
  <label for="description1">&emsp;</label>
  <input type="text" id="description1_id" name="description1_name">
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is my VBA code

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
  Dim IE As Object
  'create new instance of IE. use reference to return current IE if
  'you want to use open IE window. Easiest way I know of is via title bar
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  'Go to web page listed insde quotes
  IE.Navigate "file:///C:/Users/stren/Documents/Sample_WebForm.html"
  'Show the window
  IE.Visible = True
  'Wait until IE is done loading page
  While IE.busy
    DoEvents
  Wend
  'Fill the field with data
    IE.Document.getElementById("part1_name").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
End Sub
```

When I run the VBA code, the webform pops up, but no data is filled in the first box and I'm getting the error:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)':
Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed
```

Any ideas what's wrong with this code?

Comment: See my comment on the usage of `ie.Busy` by itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48490013/5781745 See if that solves your issue

Comment: Put a break on the last line in the Sub, run the code, and wait a little while before hitting Continue.  Does it still error?

Comment: How come this line can be valid `.getElementById("part1_name")`? Where did you find this `part1_name` as ID? Try this instead `.getElementById("part1_id")`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the html code form my laptop to a website. The handshake between VBA and the html doesn't seem to work when the code is local to my laptop. Thanks for everyone suggestions.