# I'm trying to scrape website data with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

So I will start by saying that I am very new to VBA. I am trying to extract data from the table on [this page](https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings). I haven't acomplished much as far as the code goes so take it easy on me. I am looking for some direction on how to approach it and if it can be done, which I believe it can. If anyone is able to help guide me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

```
Sub rgnbateamstats()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")


With appIE
.navigate "https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings"
.Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("proj-stats")
```

Not really sure where to go from here or if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: You should take a look [at my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48490013/5781745) why using `ieObj.Busy` alone is a bad idea.

Comment: Nice, I will add that in. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst the table layout may appear a little odd, it actually just needs a 180 in thinking. You can grab the columns by the class name and then simply loop the rows; rather than the usual looping of rows then columns.

I use a [CSS class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to grab the columns with `querySelectorAll` i.e. I target the columns by their class name. This returns a `nodeList` containing each of the columns. Below is an example of the first two columns (admittedly abbr is not visible). Each row within a column is in a `div` so if I loop the columns I get the rows within each column by grabbing the associated `div` tag collection. Then I simply loop those to write out.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, iColumns As Object, iRow As Object, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set iColumns = .document.querySelectorAll(".rgt-col")

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            For i = 0 To iColumns.Length - 1
                c = c + 1: r = 0
                Set iRow = iColumns.item(i).getElementsByTagName("div")
                For j = 0 To iRow.Length - 1
                    r = r + 1
                    .Cells(r, c) = iRow(j).innerText
                Next
            Next
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

References:

VBA > Tools > References > Microsoft Internet Controls

Or change to late bound with:

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Comment: Tbh I always look forward to seeing your scraping methods. Nicely done.

Comment: So I tried this but keep getting a "Compile Error" on "Dim IE As New InternetExplorer" - User-defined type not defined. How do I overcome this?

Comment: You need to go VBA > Tools > References and add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls.

Comment: Yep! I missed that part. Tried to edit my comments but it wouldn't let me. Works flawlessly!

Comment: No worries. I should have added it. I edited reference in  :-)

Comment: @QHarr How can I display CSS Query? Is that addon to chrome?

Answer (score 4):

This will grab the entire table on that page.

> *This project uses [**early-binding**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation). You will need to **set references** to:*
>
> - Microsoft Internet Controls
> - Microsoft HTML Object Library
>
> You can accomplish this within the VBE > Tools > References.

I will say, this site uses a very strange method on setting up their tables, and it was interesting to figure out a decent way to accomplish this.

Also, another thing that you may or may not be okay with is that there are **hidden** columns in this table that doesn't show on the site but will show in your excel document. If you are not okay with this, you can simply remove or hide them after this code is executed - or if you're up to modifying this to prevent that from happening during execution, more power to you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub rgnbateamstats()

    Const url$ = "https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings"

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    With IE
        .Navigate url
        .Visible = True
        ieBusy IE
        Set doc = .Document
    End With
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, tCol As HTMLDivELement
    Dim subTbls(): subTbls = Array("rgt-bdy left", "rgt-bdy mid", "rgt-bdy right")
    
    Dim subTbl As Long        
    For subTbl = 0 To 2
        For Each tCol In getSubTblCols(doc, subTbls(subTbl)).getElementsByClassName("rgt-col")
            c = c + 1
            For r = 1 To tCol.getElementsByTagName("div").Length
                ws.Cells(r, c) = tCol.getElementsByTagName("div")(r - 1).innerText
            Next
        Next tCol
    Next subTbl

End Sub
```

```
Private Function getSubTblCols(doc As HTMLDocument, ByVal className$) As HTMLDivElement
    Dim tbl As HTMLTable
    Set tbl = doc.getElementById("proj-stats")
    Set getSubTblCols = tbl.getElementsByClassName(className)(0).Children(0). _
            Children(1)
End Function
```

```
Private Sub ieBusy(ieObj As InternetExplorer)
    With ieObj
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Okay, time to attempt what's going on here.

There are **three** sub-tables in your table. This is the best way to explain it, but this means you will first loop through each sub table with this line:

```
For subTbl = 0 To 2
```

Within that loop, you will loop that sub-table's columns with this line:

```
For Each tCol In getSubTblCols(doc, subTbls(subTbl)).getElementsByClassName("rgt-col")
```

`rgt-col` is the class name for the column in each table - so at least that part was easy. The function `getSubTblCols` grabs the main sub-table element class name of one of the three names of the sub table in the array `subTbls()`.

`c` is your Excel column number, `r` is the row number. You also use `r` for each of the HTML's row numbers, but it's uses `base 0`, so you have to subtract 1.

Then get the cell's value using the `innerText` property of the cell, place that into your spreadsheet, then rinse and repeat.

I moved your busy webpage function to a new sub, `ieBusy`. I also added the `.readyState` property because as I stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018755/im-trying-to-scrape-website-data-with-excel-vba/53019300#comment92940528_53018755) that `.busy` by itself is unreliable at best.

Comment: Edit - Thanks! This seems to work great. I missed the references in the yellow box. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this part for extracting first column

```
Set allrowofdata = appIE.document.getElementById("proj-stats")

Set newobj = allrowofdata.getElementsByClassName("rgt-col")(0)

For Each x In newobj.Children
r = r + 1
Cells(r, 1).value = x.innerText
Next x
```

Comment: Adding this worked for the first column! That was exciting to see it start working! Now to figure out how to modify to pull the rest. Thanks for the head start!