# Can I recycle a webscraping Excel VBA script for other sites?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

So in my previous post, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018755/im-trying-to-scrape-website-data-with-excel-vba), everyone that chimed in was such a big help but unfortunately I didn't learn much from it. Is it possible to recycle one of those scripts to scrape [this page](https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/nba-lineups.php) and pull confirmed/projected lineups in to Excel? Upon looking at the html, I see that they are housed in a "lineups is-compact" div class then separated in "lineup is-nba" div class.

I am trying to get Team name, Player Name and expected/confirmed.

Here are other sites providing the same info it they are easier to pull from.

[RotoGrinders](https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nba?site=draftkings) < Same place the other code was create for
[BB Monster](https://basketballmonster.com/nbalineups.aspx)

This is the code I ended up using because it seemed simpler to modify for other tasks. Boy was I wrong.

```
Option Explicit 
Public Sub GetInfo()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, iColumns As Object, iRow As Object, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://rotogrinders.com/team-stats/nba-earned?site=draftkings"

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Set iColumns = .document.querySelectorAll(".rgt-col")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 0 To iColumns.Length - 1
            c = c + 1: r = 0
            Set iRow = iColumns.item(i).getElementsByTagName("div")
            For j = 0 To iRow.Length - 1
                r = r + 1
                .Cells(r, c) = iRow(j).innerText
            Next
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Please keep in mind I have exactly 4 days of experience. Noob in every way.

Comment: Clarify your expected output.

Comment: Just did and also added other websites providing the same information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the enjoyable, and challenging, things about web-scraping is that generally each site is different, and often pages belonging to the same site may differ. I recognise that you only have a little experience so I'm afraid that the following is a bit of a learning curve. The script for your other answer was pretty basic in that columns in a table format where looped, then rows.

The transferable part of all this is learning how to read HTML, deciding when to use XMLHTTP (which I use below and is a faster retrieval method but won't retrieve everything off the page - particularly if the page is javascript heavy) versus a browser based solution. Practice using the inspection/dev tools to play around with selecting information.

Then there are the common bits of code you will generally use each time, for example, when using IE you will pretty much always have the same connection lines of code and wait lines of code. With xmlHttp you will generally also re-use opening lines of code. But, because web sites are generally pretty different you will need to explore how to parse the [`DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) each time to get at the info you want. With pages belonging to the same site/host, you may be able to re-use more code if their developers are consistent in their page design. Just don't expect this to be the case.

The script below uses [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), in this case a method of [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/htmldocument), to initially generate `nodeLists` by matching elements on their [class names](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp).

These lines below generate what you might think of as lists. Each element in the list having the same class name.

```
Set teamsVisitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__team.is-visit")
Set teamsHomies = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__team.is-home")
Set nickNamesVisitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__mteam.is-visit")
Set nickNamesHomies = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__mteam.is-home")
Set visitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__list.is-visit") '  then by li
Set homies = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__list.is-home") ' then by li
```

So, let's have a look at one of those lists. The `nodeList` associated with

```
Set teamsVisitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__team.is-visit")
```

[image]

You can see how this has gathered the 4 visitor team 2 letter names in to a `nodeList` (you could think collection but you can't `For Each` over it and it is in fact more like an array).

I've given the variables fairly descriptive names so you have an idea what is in each list but if unsure, you can go into your developer tools (F12 in Chrome, FireFox), highlight any bit of HTML in the elements tab and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the search HTML box and enter the text between `""` from the `querySelectorAll` into that box e.g. `.lineup__team.is-visit`

[image]

You can see it returns the number of matches in the HTML for the CSS selector. You can use enter to cycle through them.

So, I have a series of `nodeList`s. Each index, e.g. index `0`, in each `nodeList`, relates to the same match. So, at index `0` I have `GS v BKN i.e. Warriors v Nets`.

I loop the `nodeList`s writing the match info out to the sheet. In order to get the confirmed/player info I need to further subdivide the `nodeList`s I have with:

```
Set visitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__list.is-visit") '  then by li
Set homies = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__list.is-home") ' then by li
```

Take index `0` in `visitors nodeList` we have:

[image]

We need this info further split out; simply using class name wasn't enough. If we take a peek at the HTML we can see that actually, individual items are separated into [`li`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) list tag elements:

This means we can use `.getElementsByTagName` method to return these items. For example:

```
homies.item(i).getElementsByTagName("li")
```

This then ends up looking like this (sample):

[image]

In my loop I write out visitors to the left column, and home to the right. As I loop through the indices (i.e. each match) in the original `nodeList`s I add `+3` to the output column number so you get a spaced write out of each table.

---

**Example output:**

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetMatchInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/nba-lineups.php", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    Dim visitors As Object, teamsVisitors As Object, nickNamesVisitors As Object
    Dim homies As Object, teamsHomies As Object, nickNamesHomies As Object
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, j As Long

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set teamsVisitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__team.is-visit")
        Set teamsHomies = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__team.is-home")
        Set nickNamesVisitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__mteam.is-visit")
        Set nickNamesHomies = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__mteam.is-home")
        Set visitors = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__list.is-visit") '  then by li
        Set homies = .querySelectorAll(".lineup__list.is-home") ' then by li
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        r = 1: c = 1

        For i = 0 To teamsHomies.Length - 1
            .Cells(r, c) = teamsVisitors.item(i).innerText
            .Cells(r, c + 1) = teamsHomies.item(i).innerText

            r = r + 1
            .Cells(r, c) = nickNamesVisitors.item(i).innerText
            .Cells(r, c + 1) = nickNamesHomies.item(i).innerText

            Dim numHomiesLiElements As Long, numVisitorsLiElements As Long, maxNumberofLiElements As Long

            numHomiesLiElements = homies.item(i).getElementsByTagName("li").Length - 1
            numVisitorsLiElements = visitors.item(i).getElementsByTagName("li").Length - 1

            maxNumberofLiElements = IIf(numHomiesLiElements > numVisitorsLiElements, numHomiesLiElements, numVisitorsLiElements)
            For j = 0 To maxNumberofLiElements
                r = r + 1
                On Error Resume Next
                .Cells(r, c) = visitors.item(i).getElementsByTagName("li")(j).innerText
                .Cells(r, c + 1) = homies.item(i).getElementsByTagName("li")(j).innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next

            r = 1: c = c + 3
        Next

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

**Resources to help you:**

1. [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)
2. [CSS Class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)
3. [XMLHTTP requests](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)

---

See here for improved python based script:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626217/6241235

Comment: you are awesome! This is perfect, I can see where everything comes from and what to look for. Is there anyway on here to tip? I gave you a +1 but I don't feel like that is enough.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about the above? I appreciate at first it is quite a lot to take in.

Comment: No this is fantastic! I actually used your steps to write it myself using yours a reference a couple times. I am going to try to pick another site and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: One question, how did you get to the CSSQuery search you show in your screenshots? Is that an addon for chrome?