# Removing new line characters in web scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape baseball lineup data but would only like to return the player names. However, as of right now, it is giving me - position, newline character, name, newline character, and then batting side. For example I want

`'D. Fletcher'`

but instead I get

`'LF\nD. Fletcher\nR'`

Additionally, it is giving me all players on the page. It would be preferable that I group them by team, which maybe requires a dictionary set up of some sort but am not sure what that code would look like.

I've tried using the `strip` function but I believe that only removes leading or trailing issues as opposed to in the middle. I've tried researching how to just get the title information from the anchor tag but have not figured out how to do that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily_lineups.htm'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

players = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'lineup__player'})

####for link in players.find('a'):
#####   print (link.string)

awayPlayers = [player.text.strip() for player in players]
print(awayPlayers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only get the `.text` for the `a` tag, not the whole `li`:

```
awayPlayers = [player.find('a').text.strip() for player in players]
```

That would result in something like the following:

```
['L. Martin', 'Jose Ramirez', 'J. Luplow', 'C. Santana', ...
```

Comment: That does do exactly as you said it would. However, I just realized it would be preferable to get the title of the anchor tag because that does include the player's full name. Any guidance on that? Sorry I just realized that now after looking at my data that I would prefer that approach. Yours does do exactly what I asked however so I appreciate that as it may be helpful in future circumstances.

Comment: You should be able to use `player.find("a")["title"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Say you wanted to build that dict with team names and players you could do something like as follows. I don't know if you want the highlighted players e.g. Trevor Bauer? I have added variables to hold them in case needed.

Ad boxes and tools boxes are excluded via :not pseudo class which is passed a list of classes to ignore.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
team_dict = {}

teams = [item.text for item in soup.select('.lineup__abbr')] #26

matches = {}
i = 0
for teambox in soup.select('.lineups > div:not(.is-ad, .is-tools)'):
    team_visit = teams[i]
    team_home = teams[i + 1]
    highlights = teambox.select('.lineup__player-highlight-name a')
    visit_highlight = highlights[0].text
    home_highlight = highlights[1].text
    match = team_visit + ' v ' + team_home
    visitors = [item['title'] for item in teambox.select('.is-visit .lineup__player [title]')]
    home = [item['title'] for item in teambox.select('.is-home .lineup__player [title]')]
    matches[match] = {'visitor' : [{team_visit : visitors}] ,
                      'home' : [{team_home : home}]
                     }
    i+=1
```

---

**Example info:**

[image]

---

**Current structure:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that looks to be very helpful so I'll test and play around with it a bit later today. Any guidance as to how the code would be tweaked to output it to excel with teams in one column and players in the next column?

Comment: Sure thing. Let me get back to you a little later.

Comment: Thanks so much. I appreciate the help as I continue learning Python!

Comment: How are you planning on linking matches? I assume you mean team in first column then players in columns (rather than single column) to right? Would you want column A to be the match, column B the team, column C > Column _n_ the players?

Comment: Yes, Column A would be the team, column B would be the player, and Column C could be their batting order if that makes sense. Thanks again so much for your help.

Comment: What determines batting order? Is that the order the players' names are listed on the site?

Comment: Correct - it would be there index if it started at 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were almost there, you just needed to tweak it a little bit:

```
 awayPlayers = [player.find('a').text for player in players]
```

This list comprehension will grab just the names from the list then pull the text from the anchor...you get just a list of the names:

```
['L. Martin',
 'Jose Ramirez',
 'J. Luplow'...]
```

Comment: This is what the other person posted and is very helpful, so thank you. I've tweaked my needs just a touch. I actually want the "title" of the link because it gives the players full name. I tried the following code but it returns "None" for each item. Any guidance?                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                              
    for player in players:
    title = player.get('title')
    print(title)

Comment: Did not notice their post should have refreshed it. You had the answer in your question, just not all in the same place!

Comment: Also, you do not need the strip, the text comes in clean once you specify the ` find.('a').text`

Comment: just change the tag to player.find('a').get('title')

Answer (score -1):

You have to find `a` tag and `title` attribute in it, check below answer.

```
awayPlayers = [player.find('a').get('title') for player in players]
print(awayPlayers)
```

Output is:

```
['Leonys Martin', 'Jose Ramirez', 'Jordan Luplow', 'Carlos Santana',
```

Comment: That does not do what I want it to do unfortunately. I only want the name, and not the extra position and batting side data combined with the player name.Would you know how to change the scrape so it give me the anchor title? For example -         
 <a title="Leonys Martin" href="/baseball/player.php?id=12081">L. Martin</a>               I would want it to return "Leonys Martin" rather than L. Martin.  Thanks!

Comment: @ShawnSchreier I hope this is expected output you want