# VBA: Is there a way to give a SetClipboard time to clear?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, clipboard

Every time I run the code it gives me a Run Time error message ("Run-time error '91'. Object variable or With block variable not set") when it is going to a Clipboard that is set up. However, if I follow the code step by step (using Step Into), it has no issue. The code is one of many loops that calls up the clipboard. This led me to believe that it was a time issue, so I changed the time from 3 sec to 10. This worked but it's very inconsistent, one time it'll work and another it won't.

I know it has to do with the Clipboard not having enough time to empty out because it isn't just one statement. It can be any statement that calls up the Clipboard. If I run it, it could be the first clipboard statement that causes the error, or next time I run it, the fifth Clipboard callup statement could cause the problem. The only common denominator is the Clipboard.

```
            DoEvents
            D.Body.InnerHTML = H.responseText
            If Err.Number = "91" Then
                Err.Clear
            Else
                SetClipboard (D.getElementsByTagName("table")(1).outerHTML): Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")): DoEvents
                Range("Q" & LR).Select
                Sheet17.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
            End If
            Start_Date = Start_Date + 1
            End_Date = Start_Date + 1
            LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Next i
```

Comment: It's not about the clipboard. It's about not [waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58508581/11683) for the HTMLDocument to parse in the background after the `D.Body.InnerHTML = H.responseText`.

Comment: I tried adding ```:Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue ("0:00:10"))``` to it, to give it more time. That didn't work.

Comment: That freezes the current thread, which does not help in processing things.